# Neo4j - Unable to load Relations from csv

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load the data from the csv and display the nodes along with the relations as the graph in Neo4j. I am able to load the entity1 and entity2 in Neo4j, but unable to load the relations from the csv.
My csv file looks like this[image]

Below is my CYPHER Code

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////csvFiles/Fraud_Triplets_Neo4j.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (a:Subject {
 Object1:csvLine.Entity1
,display:csvLine.Entity1
 });


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
"file:////csvFiles/Fraud_Triplets_Neo4j.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (b:Object {  Object2:csvLine.Entity2 ,display:csvLine.Entity2  });

  LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////csvFiles/Fraud_Triplets_Neo4j.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (a:Subject { Object1: csvLine.Entity1})
MATCH (b:Object { Object2: csvLine.Entity2})
MERGE ((a) -[:Relation{r:csvLine.Relation}]-> (b))
```

I am getting [image: this graph]

Kindly let me know, how should i specify relation from csv file.

Comment: What is wrong with the resultant graph? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: I guess you are trying to create relationships between your nodes with the type based on the column Relation, am I right? Something like `(Michael Roberts)-[:followed up]->(Dr. Baker)`

Comment: @Bruno Peres: Exactly. I want `(Michael Roberts)-[:followed up]->(Dr. Baker)` in the relation

Comment: I believe that the answer I provided fits the requirements. Am I wrong?

Comment: It does. There is slight issue in the code. I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you question completely, but I guess you are trying to create the relationship with types based on column "Relation" of your .CSV file.

You can do it installing [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and using `apoc.create.relationship` procedure.

Also, your Cypher query can be simplified. You don't need to call `LOAD CSV` 3 times. Try something like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////csvFiles/Fraud_Triplets_Neo4j.csv" AS csvLine

MERGE (a:Subject {
    Object1:csvLine.Entity1,
    display:csvLine.Entity1
});

MERGE (b:Object {
    Object2:csvLine.Entity2,
    display:csvLine.Entity2
});

CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, csvLine.Relation, {}, b) YIELD rel

RETURN *
```

*Note: Remember to install APOC Procedures based on the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).*