# How to get relation from csv in Neo4J/Cypher using CSV LOAD

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I use Neo4J Community Edition version 3.2.1.

Consider this CSV-file with edges:

```
node1,relation,node2,type
1,RELATED_TO,2,Married
2,RELATED_TO,1,Married
1,RELATED_TO,3,Child
2,RELATED_TO,3,Child
3,RELATED_TO,4,Sibling
3,RELATED_TO,5,Sibling
4,RELATED_TO,5,Sibling
```

I have allready created the nodes for this. I then run the following csv load command:

```
load csv with headers from
"file:///test_dataset/edges.csv" as line
match (person1:Person {pid:line.node1}),
    (person2:Person {pid:line.node2})
create (person1)-[:line.relation {type:line.type}]->(person2)
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Invalid input '.': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '|', a length specification, a property map or ']' (line 5, column 24 (offset: 167))
"create (person1)-[:line.relation {type:line.type}]->(person2)"
```

It seems that I cannot use "line.relation" like this. How can I use the relation from the csv-file (second column) using csv load?

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408133/5759828), but I would like to do this using native query language.

To verify that the rest of the query is correct I have managed to create the edges correctly by hardcoding the relation like this:

```
load csv with headers from
"file:///test_dataset/edges.csv" as line
match (person1:Person {pid:line.node1}),
    (person2:Person {pid:line.node2})
create (person1)-[:RELATED_TO {type:line.type}]->(person2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Natively **it's not possible** to create a node with a *dynamic label* and a relationship with a *dynamic type*.

That's why there is a procedure for that.

If you want to do it natively and you know all the distinct value of your `relation` column, you can create many cypher script like that (one per value):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test_dataset/edges.csv" AS line
WITH line WHERE line.relation ='RELATED_TO'
MATCH (person1:Person {pid:line.node1})
MATCH (person2:Person {pid:line.node2})
CREATE (person1)-[:RELATED_TO {type:line.type}]->(person2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Then I will look into the importing tool.